# what's the difference between ordinal and hint number in the native dll?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

I would like to know any difference between ordinal and hint value in the native dlls? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ordinals can be thought of as the alternative (internal) name of a exported function (All exports have a ordinal and some only have the ordinal a.k.a. [NONAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). They were common in 16-bit windows but not so much these days (The import/export tables are smaller if you don't include the "string name"). They are slightly faster for the loader to look-up and are often used for undocumented functions. The downside is that they might not be stable from release to release.

The [hint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/17/9980011.aspx) is used by the loader as a shortcut into the dll export table, if the hint offset does not match the expected function name the normal search is used.

Take a look at [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) for more details about the different PE sections.

Comment: Ordinals are sometimes used to hide exported symbol names (e.g. Often used by MFCxx.dll)

Answer (score 0):

tools like dependencywalkers and PeStudio show the relation between ordinals and hints.